# Compatibility mode Force on IE not working

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

I am doing the following meta tag to force the page to run in IE9

```
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

However, based on my research, it appears the following is causing the meta tag above not to work (here is the [link](https://ilia.ws/archives/196-IE8-X-UA-Compatible-Rant.html) that describes why):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

There is a solution in PHP but I am not certain if I can run the code. My question is: Is their an alternative solution that does not involve PHP? Can it be done in VB?

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind that [support for IE9 ended on January 12, 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support); also: [What does <meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=edge”> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/1115360)

You can use IIS to add the header: [How to add a custom HTTP response header to a Web site that is hosted by IIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/954002/how-to-add-a-custom-http-response-header-to-a-web-site-that-is-hosted).

You can use [a setting in web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/) to add the header.

In the VB.NET, you can use [HttpResponse.AppendHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7")
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Andrew: I tried the approach that was provided, within the header tags "<head></head>" and it throws an 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @user9808783 The code snippet I showed is intended to be used in a code-behind file. Are you trying to put your code in the .aspx file instead of the .aspx.vb file?

Comment: @user9808783 OK, you should be able to press F7 to get to the code-behind file. Put the code just before the line `End Class`. Remember to build the solution.